# Adding "Successors" columns using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

How do I set an additional column in MS Project?

I tried the record macro option and copy-pasted the code but still facing errors.

```vb
Sub addcolumn()
' Macro addcolumn
    SelectTaskColumn Column:="Add New Column"
    TableEditEx Name:="&Entry", TaskTable:=False, NewName:="", FieldName:="Text1", NewFieldName:="Successors", Title:="", ColumnPosition:=8
    TableApply Name:="&Entry"
End Sub
```

Receive this error:

> Run-time error '1004':
> The field "Successors" does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Successors is a Task field, the second argument needs to be True:

```
TableEditEx Name:="&Entry", TaskTable:=True, NewName:="", FieldName:="Text1", NewFieldName:="Successors", Title:="", ColumnPosition:=8
```

See [Application.TableEditEx method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.tableeditex) for more details.